# Difference between Promise.all, webdriver.promise.all, protractor.promise.all

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, protractor

I have a protractor test in which I use `protractor.promise.all` to resolve several promises and it works fine. However, if I change to use `Promise.all` instead of `protractor.promise.all` I get some error. So I think there is a significant difference between them. My questions:

1) What is the difference between:

```
webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
webdriver.promise.all
```

and

```
protractor.promise.all
```

and

```
Promise.all
```

2) How can I find all the cases where I have to use protractors own implementation instead of the standard. Is there a documentation about these special cases?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`protractor.promise` provides you a quick access to the *webdriver promise* and is the same as `webdriver.promise`. But [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is a built-in EcmaScript 2015 object for asynchronous computations.

In Protractor, there is this ["Control Flow" mechanism](http://www.protractortest.org/#/control-flow) that controls the queue of webdriver promises to resolve them in order and keep thing organized. If you want for your promises to be handled with Control Flow, use webdriver promises via `protractor.promise`.